# git merge ou rebase

Tags: git

Quando programo utilizando git, sempre utilizo `merge` da minha branch no master para adicionar novos códigos, porém algumas ferramentas gráficas como o [smartgit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) fazem um rebase ao invés do merge.

Devo utilizar o comando `rebase` ou `merge` para adicionar minhas mudanças na minha branch master?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Vamos considerar o cenário abaixo para entender melhor o que ocorrer e qual opção usar:

```
--- A --- B --- C --- D --- remotes/origin/master
           \
            --- E --- F --- master
```

Digamos que você baseou seu trabalho no commit B, e criou os commits E e F, e, enquanto isso, foram adicionados os commits C e D no branch remoto. O `merge` pode funcionar de duas formas: *fast forward* e *merge commit*. O fast forward só funciona se você não fez commit nenhum, o que não é o caso. Nos casos em que o fast forward é possível, não há diferença entre usar ele e o rebase.

O merge commit vai ficar assim:

```
--- A --- B --- C --- D --- remotes/origin/master
           \           \
            --- E --- F --- M --- master
```

Isto é, ele cria o commit M, que tem dois pais: os últimos commits do seu branch e do branch que você está fazendo merge.

Já o rebase fica assim:

```
--- A --- B --- C --- D --- remotes/origin/master
                       \
                        --- E' --- F' --- master
```

A principal vantagem do rebase é que sua história permanece linear: todo commit tem um único pai. Mas note que os commits E e F não existem mais no seu branch: o que existem são commits E' e F', que são equivalentes aos E e F originais, mas diferentes. A principal desvantagem é a seguinte: digamos que você tenha publicado o seu branch no repositório "meurepo":

```
--- A --- B --- C --- D --- remotes/origin/master
           \
            --- E --- F --- master, remotes/meurepo/master
```

E outra pessoa fez fork desse seu repositório e fez algo nele:

```
--- A --- B --- C --- D --- remotes/origin/master
           \
            --- E --- F --- master, remotes/meurepo/master
                       \
                        --- G --- remotes/outrorepo/master
```

Agora você fez o rebase, e adicionou um commit:

```
--- A --- B --- C --- D --- remotes/origin/master
           \           \
            \           --- E' --- F' --- H -- master
             \
              - E --- F --- G --- remotes/outrorepo/master
```

Agora a outra pessoa tem problemas sérios. Os commits E e F e os commits E' e F' são diferentes, o que pode trazer sérios problemas para a outra pessoa se ela tentar fazer merge. Além disso, a outra pessoa não pode fazer um rebase com a mesma facilidade que você (é possível, mas requer que ela saiba exatamente o ponto em que você fez o rebase -- trivial acima, mas nem tanto na prática).

Vamos ver como fica a opção de fazer merge, e já vou incluir o branch da outra pessoa:

```
--- A --- B --- C --- D --- remotes/origin/master
           \               \
            --- E --- F --- M -- H -- master, remotes/meurepo/master
                       \
                        --- G --- remotes/outrorepo/master
```

Observe que agora foi criado um commit M. Esse commit tem dois pais: D e F. A principal *desvantagem* desse tipo de operação é justamente essa falta de linearidade. Fica mais difícil localizar o momento exato em que algum problema foi introduzido no código (no exemplo acima parece fácil, mas pense como fica se todo mundo faz merges desse tipo regularmente).

Existem duas vantagens. A primeira é que fazer merge disso é mais simples: como a história foi preservada, o git já sabe que os commits E e F são comuns entre remotes/meurepo/master e remotes/outrorepo/master, e podem ser ignorados na hora de verificar conflitos.

A outra vantagem é que é mais fácil entender o que as pessoas que estavam trabalhando no código estavam pensando. Digamos que uma outra pessoa criou um bug em H, causado pela interação de C com E. No caso de merge, ela sabe que C e E foram desenvolvidos de forma independente, e por isso a interação é inesperada. No caso do rebase, ela vai achar que você já sabia da interação ao criar E', pois a história é linear, e vai ficar na dúvida se foi intencional ou não.

A regra que me parece ser a mais recomendada é a seguinte: enquanto você não publicar seu branch, pode fazer rebase. Uma vez publicado, faça merge. Entretanto, rebases são muito utilizados na comunidade Linux, que é a criadora do git, o que serve de contraponto.

Comment: Bom ponto na última frase: rebase não é uma coisa possível de fazer com patches uma vez publicados.

Comment: Muito bem explicado. Os rebases são incríveis pra deixar o "desenho" bonito, mas pra trabalhar em conjunto são desaconselháveis, assim como afirmou o @epx acima. Agora se só você está com a "feature branch" no seu repositório, ou se tem certeza que só você mexeu nela, daí vale muito a pena fazer o `rebase`. Com o rebase, também, fica fácil retirar alguma funcionalidade caso seja necessário.

Answer (score 8):

Depende em parte do seu gosto.

O "merge" reúne duas linhas de desenvolvimento separadas. É mais fácil de fazer e qualquer desenvolvedor pode a qualquer momento fazer um merge com o repositório "oficial".

Porém muitos mantenedores de projetos que usam Git não gostam dos commits de merge, pois eles são meio opacos. Cada commit de merge tem dois "pais" diferentes. A história do projeto deixa de ser linear.

Já o "rebase" permite reescrever a "história" do repositório. Entre outras coisas isto permite reformar seus commits antes de serem mandados ao repositório "oficial".

Isto permite manter a ilusão que o histórico do desenvolvimento é perfeitamente linear e serial, um commit tendo apenas um pai. Facilita muito, por exemplo, fazer um teste de regressão para localizar que commit introduziu um bug.

Para referência, artigos que escrevi a respeito: [Git merge: one legitimate use and a goof](http://epx.com.br/artigos/gitmerge.php) e [The many faces of git rebase](http://epx.com.br/artigos/gitfaces.php)