# Este tipo de merge é correto?

Tags: git, github

Estou fazendo o seguinte método para administrar meus branchs, porém não sei se é o mais correto:

Eu crio um branch com `git branch -b newbranch` e comito as mudanças. Então quando faço uma atualização eu simplesmente adiciono os arquivos e `git commit --amend` e então `git push origin newbranch -f`. Assim sempre deixo meu branch com um commit. Quando vou subir pro master faço o seguinte:

```
git checkout newbranch
git rebase master
git push origin branch -f
```

Resolvo os conflitos, assim o branch vai ficar atualizado e então:

```
git checkout master
git rebase newbranch
git push origin master
```

Resolvo os conflitos e então deleto o branch.

Foi assim que me ensinaram, mas vi que existe o merge, que aparenta ser muito mais simples, porém nos projetos que participei me falaram que essa maneira que mostrei o `tig` fica mais organizado, pois não mostra os desmembramentos da árvore e tudo fica mais organizado.

A questão é que tomei a liderança dos projetos, e quero mudar esse tipo de merge com rebase para o merge normal, só que não sei se é a mesma coisa ou se o merge é mais seguro. Existe alguma padrão que é usado?

Comment: E faz sentido ter tudo em apenas um commit? E se você quiser reverter apenas uma pequena mudança feita dentro desta branch?

Comment: Por isto mesmo que estou querendo mudar, pra mim o merge faz mais sentido, mas me ensinaram assim.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [git merge ou rebase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6189/git-merge-ou-rebase)

Comment: cara, a melhor forma de trabalhar com git hoje é usando o Conceito Git Flow, vale a pena dar uma estudada nele, exemplo, `git checkout master`, `git checkout -b develop`, `git checkout -b feature/algo && git add . && git commit -m "[ tag ] o que foi criado" && git push origin feature/algo` isso é só um exemlplo

Comment: Ambos "fazem sentido", depende de como vc quer trabalhar. Acho que vale mais a pena entender a diferença entre eles, e aí vc decide o que faz mais sentido ou é "melhor" no seu caso (pois "melhor" é relativo), dê uma lida [aqui](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) e [aqui](https://hackernoon.com/git-merge-vs-rebase-whats-the-diff-76413c117333) (além do link já citado como duplicata). Mas resumindo, o rebase deixa o histórico mais limpo e linear (ao custo de ter que reescrevê-lo), enquanto o merge é o contrário (não altera o histórico, mas ele fica mais "poluído").

Comment: Quanto ao `commit --amend`, eu diria que é um "uso torto" do comando, pois [é possível juntar commits de outras maneiras](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+squash). Se optar pelo merge, por exemplo, dá pra fazer [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051)

Comment: Embora a pergunta seja muito interessante (e pertinente), quando alguém menciona "fazer **x** está correto?" e eu vejo que deu certo, eu me lembro da [melhor metodologia ágil de todas](https://sou.gohorseprocess.com.br/extreme-go-horse-xgh/)