# É possível transferir arquivos de uma branch para uma branch principal? (GitHub)

Tags: git, github, branch

Oi, gente! Minha dúvida é referente ao GitHub.

Subi arquivos para uma branch que não é principal, e quero passar para a branch principal (main).
Existe algum comando no Git Bash para fazer isto?

(No caso seriam arquivos de uma pasta única no meu pc, quero só trocar os arquivos para a branch principal!!).

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: esta se referindo em passar os arquivos para branch principal? de uma olhada sobre o `git merge <branch>` [aqui neste artigo.](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/git-merge-e-git-rebase-quando-usa-los/)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [git merge ou rebase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6189/git-merge-ou-rebase)

Comment: Obrigada! Entender o funcionamento das branchs é essencial. Git merge funcionou.